# Check for a specific word not in a paragraph

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to check for a specific word **not** in a given paragraph.

The following excluded words should **not** be in my paragraph.

```
<script>
<src>
<img>
```

I tried this regular expression and it worked only for one single line paragraph. It does not work for multiline paraghraphs.

```
"^(((?!^.*k(script|src|img)k)).*)*$";
```

Comment: Define "paragraph". Also, what are the `k`s surrounding your keywords supposed to do?

Comment: Which programming language is this?

Comment: @muntoo: PHP, obviously, from the `preg-match` tag.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Not obvious to non-PHP'ers. [tag:preg-match] does not have a tag summary.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Are you trying to ensure that the text in question does not contain unwanted HTML? That is somewhat different to merely searching for excluded 'words'.

Comment: shan, welcome to stackoverflow. Your question is a bit hard to answer because some information is missing. Do you want to filter HTML input? Do you want to remove these tags? Or do you just want to test if one of those tags exists or not? And can you add some of your code what you tried so far, so it's more clear what a paragraph is and what this is about?

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what you are saying exactly, but:

If you want to verify a 'paragraph' does not contain the given 'words', just use this:

```
if(!Regex(paragraph, "^.*?<(script|src|img).*?>.*$")
{
    // Does not contain.
}
```

Comment: This won't work since it only looks for those tags at the start of each line.